Power BI relational q, have a table with hourly times and being asked to bring in data by minute
I have a report that has been pulling in hourly power measures.  I need to be able to show these measures by the minute.  I have a table with transaction dates in hours and kWh. I also have a table with the transaction date in minutes but no kW data.  the row counts have increased greatly with the small granularity.  How can I connect these tables so that I can make a graph showing the kW for each hour and be able to drill through to get Kw per min?
Thanks in advance!
Ive tried a mapping table which included both hourly and minute ( the transaction date includes the minutes but in the hourly table its formatted to just show the hour..done in the query).  basically the rows go from 400K to 15 mil.

Please illustrate your data by providing code blcoks and relevant schema.
Make sure to fix typos as well.
